# Drupal views list with the node loading with ajax

Tags: views, ajax

I have a list of articles made with views and its in a  sidebar on the left side of the page i want the article to show up in the content area when its clicked without the page reloading.
i found this website but its old from 2012 and im not sure if this would work.[LINK](http://mrkadin.com/blog/node/70?page=1)

EDIT:i did just like in the link and it worked my quesion now would be if its possible to do it with a views page and not a basic page content because i want the first item on that page to be always latest

Comment: the link is not opening